# Feed listBox from different classes c#

Tags: c#, listbox

here some beginners question after 2 hours of googling.

I have got a WindowsForm named GUI with an listbox item (it not have to be a listbox)

What I want to realize is having a box in the GUI an send from every classes in my project text to that box.

Example:
in Programm.cs I want simply write something like this GUI.WriteToLog("Hello World");
and it should appear in that box.

This GUI.WriteToLog should work in every class.

I tried to write a static function WriteToLog in the GUI class but if its static I cant use the listBox1 in that function.

```
    public partial class GUI : Form
{
        public void WriteToLog(string msg)
    {


        listBox1.Items.Add(msg);

    }
}
```

Here the class that should access the box:

```
    class FileManager
{

        internal static void RenameFiles(string filePath)
    {
        GUI g = new GUI();
        g.WriteToLog("Moving Files");
        try {
            File.Move(filePath, filePath + ".RDY");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.ToString();
            string caption = "Error";
            MessageBox.Show(message, caption);
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

More Details what I want to do:
I have to access the ListBox from all of my classes, because it should inform about status. After some more google searches. I figured out that the best way to do this is to write an event ? I this right ? How du I do this ? Example what I want: GUI with the ListBox ... I'm in class "FileManager" Function "RenameFile" there I want write one line to the ListBox "Hey, I'm renaming files now" or I'm in Class "Communicator" in Function "SendEmail" so I want to add a line to the ListBox "Hey dude, I'm sending a fabilous email" ...

Comment: can u add your code; what u have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method `RenameFiles` you create a new instance of the class called GUI. So you're not using the same form.
You can fix your code by using dependency injection when creating your GUI class so that the `FileManager` has access without needing to create a new class.
By adding something like this to the `FileManager` and calling the setter on creation of your GUI.

```
private GUI gui;
public void SetGUI(GUI g)
{
    this.gui = g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is use singleton pattern below an example:

```
 public partial class GUI
{
    private static GUI _instance;

    public static GUI Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new GUI()); }

    }

    public void WriteToLog(string msg)
    {
        //[your code]...
    }
}

class FileManager
{
    internal static void RenameFiles(string filePath)
    {
        GUI.Instance.WriteToLog("Moving Files");
        // [other code]...

    }
}
```

Comment: nope, this could be compiled but the ListBox stays empty